# how to calculate time difference in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, timestamp

I have a field that is a timestamp.  I want to calculate the time difference between that timestamp and the current time and show the time as something humanly readable like

`2 days remaining #don't show hours when > 1 day is remaining`

once less than 1 day is remaining I'll have a javascript countdown ticker.

Answer (score 0):

I've built the `dotiw` library to do exactly this: http://github.com/radar/dotiw.

This is based off the `distance_of_time_in_words` method in Rails which is not quite accurate enough, and so I've made it more accurate with `dotiw`.

Comment: just added your gem to my gemfile. thanks. But how would the logic of not showing any hours when time left is more than a day be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if end_date < Time.now # ended already
  return 'Ended'
elsif end_date > (Time.now + 1.day) # more than 1 day away
  diff_in_days = ((end_date - Time.now).to_i / 1.day)
  days_string = diff_in_days.to_s
  days_string += (diff_in_days > 1) ? ' Days' : ' Day'
  return days_string
else # ending today
  diff_in_HMS = Time.at(end_date - Time.now).gmtime.strftime('%R:%S')
  return diff_in_HMS
end
```

It prints "X Days" if end_date is > 1 day away, HH:MM:SS if ending today, and "Ended" if end_date was in the past.